# Action Mailer Variable Definition Explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to fully understand a line of code in the action mailer that is shown in every documentation but not really explained.

```
def welcome_email(user)
 @user = user #don't understand exactly which user this is
 mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Do you have any spam?')
end
```

I thought you had to define that variable like User.find(params[:id]) or User.first or something else that retrieves a specific user.  What does plain 'user' mean in this context?

Thanks for your help with this beginner level question.

Comment: You pass user as argument to welcome_email method and that is what gets set in instance variable, which in turn is passed on to your email template. Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html for details on how action mailer works and btw your website is down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user = user`

This line is setting the value of `@user` instance variable to `user` which is being passed as a variable to the `welcome_email` method.

`@user` instance variable can be accessed in the views linked to this mailer.

Where-ever the `welcome_email` method is called, it is likely to have set the value of `user` using `user = User.find(params[:id])` or `user = User.first` or something similar, and that `user` is passed in as a parameter with `welcome_email(user)` call.

Assuming the mailer is called `Notifier`, and the welcome email has to be sent when the user signs up, the following code is likely to be in the `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    ...
    @user = ...
    Notifier.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash, what I still don't understand is where the value of 'user' is coming from.  Where is that set?